# Any other ways to access Documents Directory on iDevice Locked State?

Tags: ios, objective-c, documentsdirectory

I am implementing Music Player application in iOS platform. Here I am storing and retrieving the media contents using Documents directory. So I can't able to access the 'Documents Directory' when iPhone is getting locked with passcode. I referred Apple developer library, they said the Encryption & Decryption is comes under the accessing the file contents from documents directory. **So if device is getting locked the Decryption key is Destroyed**. Here I have attached the Screen shot of Problem Description. I was stuck with this problem last 2 months. Pls give me any other ways to access the Documents directory at locked state. Not Only Media , Any other content*.

Thanks in Advance.

[image: Screen Shot]

Apple Developer Site:
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGuide/FileSystemOverview/FileSystemOverview.html

Comment: If apple said it is not possible then it is not possible. (without jailbreak/break the security system)

Comment: But Other Music Applications, how does support. @BryanChen

Comment: Have you set the correct UIBackgroundMode for audio in your info.plist to allow your device to run as a background task?

Comment: Yeah. this link will give you more detailed. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21875213/avaudioplayer-is-not-playing-in-background-when-iphone-is-locked pls look at this.

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify the file protection level as an option when you write your files. Example:

```
[someData writeToFile:filePath options:NSDataWritingFileProtectionNone error:&error];
```

In this, `someData` is an NSData representation of the data you want to write to disk, `filePath` is the string path where you want to save the file.

Read the documentation on `NSDataWritingOptions` in the [NSData Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/classes/NSData_Class/Reference/Reference.html) for more encryption options.

Comment: Thanks for your help.Its working fine for first file. For ex. First song is playing perfectly. but the next Song is not playing Automatically.If I unlock the device is playing. Can you help me? @skladek

Comment: Is the first file playing before the device locks? How have you set up the queue for songs to load and play the next song?

Comment: Yeah. I am not used AVQueuePlayer. Just I used Array of file paths and just replacing the new path after finished first song. That Audiodidfinishloading - delegate also calling. but not working? can you tell me?